# Windows Server 2012 Metro shortcut icons do not show for other users

Tags: windows-server-2012

I have installed SQL Server 2012 and SharePoint 2013 on my Windows Server 2012 machine using a dedicated domain install account.

When I log into the same machine with a user account, all the icons for these applications are missing!

I can still access the applications by finding them in 'Program Files', however it is very annoying. (For example, I'm not exactly sure where the SharePoint PowerShell is located, and frankly I don't want to know either)

In previous versions of Windows Server, the Icons always showed up in the Start Menu.

Does anyone know how I can copy the shortcuts in one account to another?

Comment: To be clear: You don't see the icons when you press Win-Q?

Comment: Win-Q does show all the icons! I can also pin those icons back to the 'Start' menu. However I still would like to see these automatically in the Start Menu. It seems all the shortcuts are kept in 'C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\' however I'm not sure why they do not appear automatically for new users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<kbd>Win</kbd>-<kbd>Q</kbd> is roughly equivalent to the All Programs item on the Start menu in previous versions of Windows; it's what you would hit to choose a program not directly on the Start screen.

Generally, you will only get program icons added directly to the Start screen if you are the user who installed the program.

If you're trying to deploy Windows Metro style apps, [Microsoft has a great guide for doing this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsstore/archive/2012/04/25/deploying-metro-style-apps-to-businesses.aspx).

Unfortunately at the moment there aren't any really good ways to enforce the content of each user's Start screen, [unless you're willing to reimage the workstation](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj134269). Hopefully a Group Policy template will be forthcoming...

Comment: This is a good shortcut to know. I have immediately memorised it next to `Windows+D` and `Ctrl+Alt+Break`

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I can see this issue confusing many people, however Win-Q really works for me.